# Postprocessing floating point numbers

Tags: pgfplotstable

A computed column, `columnWithFloatingPointNumbers`, is added to the table, `\table`. Then I am trying to compute geometric mean of this newly-added column.
However I get this error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y1' (in '1Y1.1328e1]').
```

If I use `\pgfmathprintnumberto`, I get this error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '$11.33$' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '$11.33$'..
```

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{filecontents}{table.txt}
cA  P   Sp
A   16  15.1
B   4   3.2
C   8   6.7
D   4   3.5
E   16  10.9
F   8   7.2
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{table.txt}\table

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/assign/.code={
\global\edef\tp{\thisrow{Sp}}
\global\edef\p{\thisrow{P}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathparse{\tp * 14.16 / \p}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
\global\edef\entry{\pgfmathresult}
%\pgfmathprintnumberto[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2]{\entry}{\entryb}
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
}]{columnWithFloatingPointNumbers}\table

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={cA, P, Sp,columnWithFloatingPointNumbers }, columns/cA/.style={string type},columns/cB/.style={string type},columns/columnWithFloatingPointNumbers/.style={column name={FP}, column type=l, numeric type}]\table 
\end{document}
```

Here is MWE with geomean part: (I need the geomean part to work with the column `columnWithFloatingPointNumbers`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{filecontents}{table.txt}
cA  P   Sp
A   16  15.1
B   4   3.2
C   8   6.7
D   4   3.5
E   16  10.9
F   8   7.2
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{table.txt}\table

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/assign/.code={
\global\edef\tp{\thisrow{Sp}}
\global\edef\p{\thisrow{P}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathparse{\tp * 14.16 / \p}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
\global\edef\entry{\pgfmathresult}
%\pgfmathprintnumberto[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2]{\entry}{\entryb}
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\entry
}]{columnWithFloatingPointNumbers}\table

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={cA, P, Sp,columnWithFloatingPointNumbers }, columns/cA/.style={string type},columns/cB/.style={string type},columns/columnWithFloatingPointNumbers/.style={column name={FP}, column type=l, numeric type}]\table 

\foreach \col in {P} {% I want geomean for the column  columnWithFloatingPointNumbers
    \pgfmathsetmacro\sum{0}%
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,6} {%           
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ir{\x-1}  % get number without .0
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\ir}{\col}\of\table%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\val}{\pgfplotsretval}%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
                \pgfmathparse{\sum + (ln \val)}%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
            \global\let\sum\pgfmathresult%
    }%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathparse{\sum /  6} %
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \global\let\sum\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathparse{exp \sum}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \global\let\sum\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto{\sum}{\fsum}%
    Geomean: \fsum
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The example doesn't compile to begin with: the table has no `cB` column, for instance. It's anyway a bad idea to globally set `\sum`, which is a LaTeX command; use `\Sum` or something else.

Comment: Dear @egreg, thanks for the remark about `\Sum`. I have just switched to TexStudio and it was running in nonstop mode, so I have missed removing the columns while I was trying to minimize the sample code.

Comment: I get `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y1' (in '1Y1.33635e1]').`

Comment: Dear @egreg, I have added one more MWE and updated them: The first MWE does not calculate geomean, the second MWE calculates geomean but it calculates geomean of another column, `P`. I need the geomean part to work with the column `columnWithFloatingPointNumbers`. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you generate the final column.  Using `creat col/expr` is much simpler, uses the floating point library, and produces the correct type of result.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{filecontents}{table.txt}
cA  P   Sp
A   16  15.1
B   4   3.2
C   8   6.7
D   4   3.5
E   16  10.9
F   8   7.2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{table.txt}\mytable

\pgfplotstableset{
  create on use/columnWithFloatingPointNumbers/.style={
    create col/expr={\thisrow{Sp}*14.16/\thisrow{P}}}
}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={cA,P,Sp,columnWithFloatingPointNumbers},
  columns/cA/.style={string type},
  columns/cB/.style={string type},
  columns/columnWithFloatingPointNumbers/.style={
  column name={FP}, column type=l, numeric type}]\mytable 

\foreach \col in {P,Sp,columnWithFloatingPointNumbers} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mysum{0}%
  \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{\col}\of\mytable\as\val{%
     \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
         \pgfmathparse{\mysum + (ln \val)}%
     \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
     \global\let\mysum\pgfmathresult%
  }%
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof\mytable
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
    \pgfmathparse{exp(\mysum / \pgfplotsretval)}%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
  \global\let\mysum\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto{\mysum}{\fsum}%
  Geomean of \col: \fsum\par
}%

\end{document}
```

In the above code I have also tried to avoid reusing names of standard latex commands, have used `pgfplotstable`'s commands for running over elements of a column and have shortened your mathematics computations.

Comment: Dear @AndrewSwann, thanks for the solution with `create col/exp`! When I need to retrieve value from another table (e.g. using `\pgfplotstablegetelem{\ir}{\col}\of\table`), then how I can achieve both this and taking geomean?

Comment: Your looping code with `\pgfplotstablegetelem` still works, provided the table element is created correctly in the first place.  I used `\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement` merely for efficiency.